# Binary Formatter Deserialization Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

I am using `BinaryFormatter` for serialization and deserialization.
Due to some requirement I need to change namespace name and class name.

In both the cases
--either I change namespace name or i change class name i got Serialization Exception.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you show us the exception and some code?

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` is very brittle when it comes to any kind of versioning, *especially* when it comes to the fully-qualified name of types (assembly, namespace, type-name, etc) - but also to many other factors. It *really* hates this kind of thing. Is it even *remotely* possible for you to change serializer? Literally anything else would be better than `BinaryFormattter`. Sorry, but `BinaryFormatter` is recommendable in a very small - but real - set of scenarios; most times, however, it will just hurt you over and over and over.

Comment: To convert from one format to another you need to put into your application both the old namesapce/class and new namespace/class.  The write conversion to go from old to new.  To keep track of old and new files I would add to the file name a version number so you can test if you are working with old or new format.

Comment: due to project requirement i only need to change to my namespace name and class name and rest of the structure is same between both the versions.Can we support this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this by writing your own `SerializationBinder`, i.e.

```
class MyCustomBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        // TODO: turn a Type into a pair of strings
    }
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        // TODO: turn a pair of strings into a Type
    }
}
```

You would then specify the `.Binder` on the `BinaryFormatter` instance, and it *should* work. You'll have to figure out what the old `assemblyName`/`typeName` were, etc, of course, and make sure that it behaves as such in both directions.

However... and I can't emphasize this enough: if you're hitting this problem, `BinaryFormatter` is probably just a bad choice of serializer. Many many alternative serializers exist that would do a much better job - being more efficient *and* more friendly to refactorings. Please put consideration into changing serializer.